# Kubeadm and kubectl - connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubectl

I deployed a basic cluster on two virtual machines (kvm) with one being designated as master with control plane on it using `kubeadm init` - everything sees to be starting correctly, but when I try to do even the most basic checks using `kubectl` I get connection refused error.

#### UPDATE 2:

Got it working, but don't understand why - Originally, I was running everything as dedicated user with sudo. As soon as I switch to being root (su root) and repeated the steps, everything started to work. What caused the change, is it somehow related to being in root environment instead of user? Different home directory? Working directory? I am at a loss here

#### UPDATE 1: Minimal Failing Example:

This time I made another virtual machine running ubuntu 20.04
trying to make it a replica of [This Tutorial](https://kubecampus.io/kubernetes/courses/first-kubernetes-cluster/lessons/reviewing-kubernetes-concepts-and-building-a-cluster/) as close as possible to the original example, but the last step fails just like my original issue. Is this tutorial actually complete?

Execute step By step:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
apt update
apt install -y kubelet=1.20.0-00 kubeadm=1.20.0-00 kubectl=1.20.0-00
apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
export VERSION=19.03 && curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

systemctl enable docker
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker

kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=all

>>> At this point everything fails - some service is missing?
```

**More about environment:**

- host is ubuntu 20.04 LTS, running kvm
- guest (this is where I install k8s) is ubuntu server 22.04
- host network is on 192.168.x.y
- bridge for VMs is in the 10.0.1.x/24
- UFW is *inactive*

##### Network:

###### `ip route show`

- default via 10.0.1.254 dev ens3 proto static # this is the part of the bridge that connects my virtual machine to the outside world.
- 10.0.1.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.10 # This is the IP of the machine. Machines hosting nodes will have IPs ending with 11, 12, 13, etc.
- 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown  # autogenerated by docker - never been good with the modern netmask format so I trust the docker /16 to be fine.
  I did nothing to it.

###### `cat /etc/hosts`

I added the `primary` into the hosts, rest is autogenerated.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 primary
127.0.1.1 k8-vm

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

###### docker daemon config

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

me@k8-vm:~$ kubectl get pods

```
E0117 09:10:43.476675   13492 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.10:6443: connect: connection refused
E0117 09:10:43.477525   13492 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.10:6443: connect: connection refused
E0117 09:10:43.479198   13492 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.10:6443: connect: connection refused
E0117 09:10:43.479754   13492 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.10:6443: connect: connection refused
E0117 09:10:43.481822   13492 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.10:6443: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 10.0.1.10:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I set up the config in ~/.kube/config :

```
cat ~/.kube/config 
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: secret_stuff
    server: https://10.0.1.10:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: secret_stuff
    client-key-data: secret_stuff
```

I tried flushing the iptables, but *something* is restoring it back. Suspicious entries in the iptables:

```
Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  -- !localhost/8          localhost/8          /* block incoming     localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.1            /* default/kubernetes:https has no endpoints */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:metrics has no endpoints */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

could it be that kubectl is getting blocked by iptables?

---

### logs, outputs:

**me@primary:~$ sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=172.105.148.95 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=172.105.148.95 --pod-network-cidr=10.13.13.0/16 --node-name primary**

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.29.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
W0119 09:35:48.771333    2949 checks.go:835] detected that the sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8" of the container runtime is inconsistent with that used by kubeadm. It is recommended that using "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9" as the CRI sandbox image.
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local primary] and IPs [10.96.0.1 172.105.148.95]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost primary] and IPs [172.105.148.95 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost primary] and IPs [172.105.148.95 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key


   [certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
    [kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
    [kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
    [kubeconfig] Writing "super-admin.conf" kubeconfig file
    [kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
    [kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
    [kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
    [etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
    [control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
    [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
    [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
    [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
    [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
    [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
    [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
        timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
        - The kubelet is not running
        - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
        - 'systemctl status kubelet'
        - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
        - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
        Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
        - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

@user23204747 - answering your question:

```
journalctl -fu kubelet
Jan 19 09:42:58 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:42:58.312695    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:42:59 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:42:59.476195    3063 event.go:355] "Unable to write event (may retry after sleeping)" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" event="&Event{ObjectMeta:{primary.17abb5f60468180b  default    0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil> <nil> map[] map[] [] [] []},InvolvedObject:ObjectReference{Kind:Node,Namespace:,Name:primary,UID:primary,APIVersion:,ResourceVersion:,FieldPath:,},Reason:NodeHasSufficientPID,Message:Node primary status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID,Source:EventSource{Component:kubelet,Host:primary,},FirstTimestamp:2024-01-19 09:35:52.130377739 +0000 UTC m=+0.287533886,LastTimestamp:2024-01-19 09:35:52.130377739 +0000 UTC m=+0.287533886,Count:1,Type:Normal,EventTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,Series:nil,Action:,Related:nil,ReportingController:kubelet,ReportingInstance:primary,}"
Jan 19 09:43:02 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:02.208913    3063 eviction_manager.go:282] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"primary\" not found"
Jan 19 09:43:05 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:05.289531    3063 controller.go:145] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/primary?timeout=10s\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" interval="7s"
Jan 19 09:43:05 primary kubelet[3063]: I0119 09:43:05.315765    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:73] "Attempting to register node" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:43:05 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:05.424960    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:43:05 primary kubelet[3063]: W0119 09:43:05.450439    3063 reflector.go:539] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:05 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:05.450569    3063 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:09 primary kubelet[3063]: I0119 09:43:09.129122    3063 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="af6057fbd0e43b4628685f316cffef08e6ea4a6236223120ce825681b53a45ad"
Jan 19 09:43:09 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:09.129843    3063 pod_workers.go:1298] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=etcd pod=etcd-primary_kube-system(b8faf6a4553601b5610c06ed8c93f9e3)\"" pod="kube-system/etcd-primary" podUID="b8faf6a4553601b5610c06ed8c93f9e3"
Jan 19 09:43:09 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:09.585849    3063 event.go:355] "Unable to write event (may retry after sleeping)" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" event="&Event{ObjectMeta:{primary.17abb5f60468180b  default    0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil> <nil> map[] map[] [] [] []},InvolvedObject:ObjectReference{Kind:Node,Namespace:,Name:primary,UID:primary,APIVersion:,ResourceVersion:,FieldPath:,},Reason:NodeHasSufficientPID,Message:Node primary status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID,Source:EventSource{Component:kubelet,Host:primary,},FirstTimestamp:2024-01-19 09:35:52.130377739 +0000 UTC m=+0.287533886,LastTimestamp:2024-01-19 09:35:52.130377739 +0000 UTC m=+0.287533886,Count:1,Type:Normal,EventTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,Series:nil,Action:,Related:nil,ReportingController:kubelet,ReportingInstance:primary,}"
Jan 19 09:43:12 primary kubelet[3063]: I0119 09:43:12.128675    3063 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="a9185c62d88f3192935626d7213b4378816563580b4afa1ac14b74f4029b548c"
Jan 19 09:43:12 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:12.209179    3063 eviction_manager.go:282] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"primary\" not found"
Jan 19 09:43:12 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:12.398807    3063 controller.go:145] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/primary?timeout=10s\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" interval="7s"
Jan 19 09:43:12 primary kubelet[3063]: I0119 09:43:12.427248    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:73] "Attempting to register node" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:43:12 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:12.551820    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:43:14 primary kubelet[3063]: W0119 09:43:14.542312    3063 reflector.go:539] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:14 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:14.542441    3063 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:17 primary kubelet[3063]: W0119 09:43:17.648986    3063 reflector.go:539] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1/runtimeclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:17 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:17.649087    3063 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.RuntimeClass: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1/runtimeclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:19 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:19.507898    3063 controller.go:145] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/primary?timeout=10s\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" interval="7s"
Jan 19 09:43:19 primary kubelet[3063]: I0119 09:43:19.554658    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:73] "Attempting to register node" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:43:19 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:19.679757    3063 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" node="primary"
Jan 19 09:43:19 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:19.694847    3063 event.go:355] "Unable to write event (may retry after sleeping)" err="Post \"https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events\": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused" event="&Event{ObjectMeta:{primary.17abb5f60468180b  default    0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil> <nil> map[] map[] [] [] []},InvolvedObject:ObjectReference{Kind:Node,Namespace:,Name:primary,UID:primary,APIVersion:,ResourceVersion:,FieldPath:,},Reason:NodeHasSufficientPID,Message:Node primary status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID,Source:EventSource{Component:kubelet,Host:primary,},FirstTimestamp:2024-01-19 09:35:52.130377739 +0000 UTC m=+0.287533886,LastTimestamp:2024-01-19 09:35:52.130377739 +0000 UTC m=+0.287533886,Count:1,Type:Normal,EventTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,Series:nil,Action:,Related:nil,ReportingController:kubelet,ReportingInstance:primary,}"
Jan 19 09:43:20 primary kubelet[3063]: W0119 09:43:20.761463    3063 reflector.go:539] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dprimary&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:20 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:20.761607    3063 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:159: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://172.105.148.95:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dprimary&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:21 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:21.126858    3063 certificate_manager.go:562] kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet: Failed while requesting a signed certificate from the control plane: cannot create certificate signing request: Post "https://172.105.148.95:6443/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1/certificatesigningrequests": dial tcp 172.105.148.95:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 19 09:43:22 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:22.209975    3063 eviction_manager.go:282] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"primary\" not found"
Jan 19 09:43:24 primary kubelet[3063]: I0119 09:43:24.129352    3063 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="af6057fbd0e43b4628685f316cffef08e6ea4a6236223120ce825681b53a45ad"
Jan 19 09:43:24 primary kubelet[3063]: E0119 09:43:24.130066    3063 pod_workers.go:1298] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=etcd pod=etcd-primary_kube-system(b8faf6a4553601b5610c06ed8c93f9e3)\"" pod="kube-system/etcd-primary"
```

podUID="b8faf6a4553601b5610c06ed8c93f9e3"

CRI output:

```
sudo crictl ps --all
WARN[0000] runtime connect using default endpoints: [unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead. 
ERRO[0000] validate service connection: validate CRI v1 runtime API for endpoint "unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial unix /var/run/dockershim.sock: connect: no such file or directory" 
WARN[0000] image connect using default endpoints: [unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead. 
ERRO[0000] validate service connection: validate CRI v1 image API for endpoint "unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial unix /var/run/dockershim.sock: connect: no such file or directory" 
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED              STATE               NAME                      ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
58dcdbbbbdb57       53b148a9d1963       About a minute ago   Exited              kube-apiserver            17                  aa7a744e3afca       kube-apiserver-primary
af6057fbd0e43       a0eed15eed449       3 minutes ago        Exited              etcd                      19                  12ffe5fa72b5c       etcd-primary
a20b25ee9f45e       406945b511542       3 minutes ago        Running             kube-scheduler            5                   507b8c9d8b7ab       kube-scheduler-primary
049545de2ba82       79d451ca186a6       3 minutes ago        Running             kube-controller-manager   4                   75616efa726fd       kube-controller-manager-primary
8fbf3e41714a7       79d451ca186a6       8 minutes ago        Exited              kube-controller-manager   3                   ae5e4208a01ef       kube-controller-manager-primary
4b13c766ae730       406945b511542       8 minutes ago        Exited              kube-scheduler            4                   7e4f0405277e4       kube-scheduler-primary
```

Container logs:
Those are a bit messy, but in the end it keeps spitting out the same error message, like it retries and fails

```
W0119 09:43:29.388741       1 logging.go:59] [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "127.0.0.1:2379", ServerName: "127.0.0.1:2379", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"
W0119 09:43:30.103643       1 logging.go:59] [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "127.0.0.1:2379", ServerName: "127.0.0.1:2379", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"
F0119 09:43:33.102160       1 instance.go:290] Error creating leases: error creating storage factory: context deadline exceeded
```

###### kubelet status:

```
sudo systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-01-19 13:36:51 UTC; 12min ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
   Main PID: 8539 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 37581)
     Memory: 33.6M
        CPU: 19.659s
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─8539 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.k8s.io/p>

Jan 19 13:49:18 primary kubelet[8539]: W0119 13:49:18.366543    8539 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://master-node:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp: lookup master-node on 127.0.0.53:53: server m>
Jan 19 13:49:18 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:18.366695    8539 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://master-node:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp: lookup master-no>
Jan 19 13:49:19 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:19.481598    8539 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://master-node:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/primary?timeout=10s\": dial tcp: lookup master-node on 127.0.0.53:>
Jan 19 13:49:19 primary kubelet[8539]: I0119 13:49:19.902400    8539 kubelet_node_status.go:70] "Attempting to register node" node="primary"
Jan 19 13:49:19 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:19.904293    8539 kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://master-node:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp: lookup master-node on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving" node="primary"
Jan 19 13:49:21 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:21.741936    8539 eviction_manager.go:258] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"primary\" not found"
Jan 19 13:49:26 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:26.261529    8539 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"primary.17abc31ca21e74b4", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:>
Jan 19 13:49:26 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:26.483811    8539 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://master-node:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/primary?timeout=10s\": dial tcp: lookup master-node on 127.0.0.53:>
Jan 19 13:49:26 primary kubelet[8539]: I0119 13:49:26.907141    8539 kubelet_node_status.go:70] "Attempting to register node" node="primary"
Jan 19 13:49:26 primary kubelet[8539]: E0119 13:49:26.909431    8539 kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://master-node:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp: lookup master-node on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving" node="primary"
```

Comment: What is you distro? if it's Ubuntu check UFW status and if it's Redhat base check firewalld status. these two sit on top of iptables so they can override rules of iptable i guess

Comment: host ubuntu 20.04 (just in case host is relevant) and guest is running server 22.04. UFW is inactive - looks like something is missing that minikube did for me before I tried using kubeadm.

Answer (score 0):

The `connection refused` error typically means that the request reaches the server but there is no service running on the specified port. Are you sure the api-server is started on your master node? To check the status of kube-api server using the following command:

```
Systemctl status kube-apiserver
```

- Since the kubeconfig file is located at `\~/.kube/config`, make sure to set the KUBECONFIG environment variable to point to the correct file.
- Ensure that there is network connectivity between your client machine and the master node.Verify that you can reach the master node’s IP address from your machine.
- Check the firewall and security groups. Ensure that the necessary ports for kubernetes API communication are open. By default, the kubernetes API server listens to port 6443.
- If you suspect there are suspicious entries in iptables, inspect the iptable rules using the following command

`iptables -L -n`         -   You can look for any rules that might be interfering with kubernetes API communication. You can flush the rules temporarily using command `iptables -F`

- Verify kube-proxy status on the master node using **`kubectl -n kube-system get pods -l k8s-app=kube-proxy`.**

**EDIT**

```
This error is likely caused by: - The kubelet is not running - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
```

From the above error message, The connection refused error might be caused by misconfigurations on the node such as disabled required cgroups, can certainly cause issues with the kubelet.

1. Check the status of the kubelet service on the node by running the following command.

**`systemctl status kubelet`** - This command shows failed or unhealthy kubelet. If the kubelet is not running, try starting it using **`systemctl start kubelet`**

2. Validate node configuration to ensure that it is correctly set up and check if any required **cgroups** are disabled or misconfigured.

A. If  you are using containerd as cri follow these command
change this `SystemdCgroup = false` to `SystemdCgroup = true`

```
sudo systemctl restart containerd
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

reboot your machine (may be optional)

B. Incase you are using docker as cri follow theses command
open vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
change this ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"] to "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"],

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

reboot your machine (may be optional)

Comment: systemctl  status kube-apiserver
Unit kube-apiserver.service could not be found - I suspect it is some simple error that I missed - previously I was using minikube and feel like kubeadm doesn't do something that minikube did for me without knowing

Comment: `E0119 10:58:58.113560    8539 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.1.10:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.1.10:6443: connect: connection refused`

Looks like nothing is listening on the port - and other logs confirm that the api server is not working

Comment: @user3002166, I have edited my answer with the errors you have provided, Please check and let me know if it helped. If not, I am happy to assist you further.

Comment: I reset the configuration with `containerd config default | tee /etc/containerd/config.toml` and I set the Cgroup to true, but nothing changed. How do I verify the cgroup? I only used a little bit of minikube which probably did all for me behind the scenes and now I'm lost...

Comment: I tried following those 2 blogs: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu and https://www.airplane.dev/blog/kubeadm on a new VM and got the same error, is each of them missing something that's obvious for seasoned K8s user but not for me?

Comment: @user3002166, Have you checked the ip address of the server that is trying to connect? It **[10.0.1.10]** is not added to the /etc/hosts file. Edit the hosts file on the node by adding the IP addresses and hostnames of the servers that will be part of the cluster. After adding the ip address in the hosts  file, restart the `kubeadm service`.

Comment: I added the localhost int he form `127.0.0.1   k8-vm` with k8-vm being the hostname (all the config and issues happen on the main node where the control plane is being deployed, I didn't get far enough to get to nodes

Comment: `The connection to the server 10.0.1.10:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` The error message indicates that the server is using 10.0.1.10. Please edit the /etc/hosts file  with `10.0.1.10   k8-vm` being the hostname.

Comment: I expected it should use localhost at first, but changed to `10.0.1.10` as this is the IP of the machine - this is the bridge network address which I also use to ssh into the VM - is it correct approach? Is it possible that I need to do something about CNI plugins? I assumed, kubeadm comes with it already on board, but perhaps I need to install and configure it myself?

Comment: I got it working by switching to root, but not sure how that made a difference then doing each command with sudo

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check if apiserver pod is up and running to exclude problems on that end. Try below ones on the control plane node.

First, anything suspicious in kubelet logs?

```
journalctl -fu kubelet
```

Then, container runtime logs for the pod.

```
sudo crictl ps --all  # get container_id
sudo crictl logs container_id
```

You didn't include the full `kubeadm init` command you ran, so make sure you set `--apiserver-advertise-address` correctly.

Comment: I assumed the apiserver must be an IP that's not used in the local network - I removed the configs, did `kubeadm reset` and restart. I'll add logs at  the original post since it's way too much for the comment

Comment: This needs to be the IP the API server is accessible on.

Comment: is there some extra step that was done automatically for me when using minikube and not done now to make the control plane start the api server?